# How do I use the SSLEngine methods wrap & unwrap with application data?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, nio

I'm using SSL with NIO in Java with a simple client/server proof-of-concept app. I've got the  handshake up & running just fine, but trying to encrypt & decrypt application data after is driving me nuts. I wonder if I'm missing something in terms of the intended usage?

The client has a small message in 'payload' and tries to encrypt it for transmission like this:

```
ByteBuffer inb  = ByteBuffer.allocate(payload.length);
ByteBuffer outb = ByteBuffer.allocate(
            _sslEngine.getSession().getPacketBufferSize());
SSLEngineResult result = _sslEngine.wrap(inb, outb);
_log.finer("Wrapped " + outb.position() + " octets ("
                + result + ").");
outb.flip();
_log.finer("Cyphertext: " + Buffers.toHexString(outb));
```

In the log I see:

```
FINER: Wrapped 53 octets (Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING
bytesConsumed = 13 bytesProduced = 53).
Sep 30, 2014 1:33:51 PM PoCClientServer.PoCClient write
FINER: Cyphertext: [17 03 01 00 30 ac bd c3 b8 e4 2e a5 9a 43 41 e1 3a 81 b5 cc b6 6f 9b 55 0e 1a a5 e2 97 f1 a2 be 3d ed f8 2d 45 8b 99 35 70 e3 d2 74 6d da 63 34 5a c9 35 1a 96]
```

So all seems well. The server reads this into '_net', then tries to decrypt:

```
_log.finer("Unwrapping cyphertext " + Buffers.toHexString(_net));

_app.ByteBuffer.allocate(_sslEngine.getSession().getApplicationBufferSize());
SSLEngineResult result = _sslEngine.unwrap(_net, _app);
_log.finer("Unwrapped " + _app.position()
            + " octets(" + result + ").");
_app.flip();
_log.finer("==> " + Buffers.toHexString(_app));
```

Which produces:

```
FINER: Unwrapping cyphertext [17 03 01 00 30 ac bd c3 b8 e4 2e a5 9a 43 41 e1 3a 81 b5 cc b6 6f 9b 55 0e 1a a5 e2 97 f1 a2 be 3d ed f8 2d 45 8b 99 35 70 e3 d2 74 6d da 63 34 5a c9 35 1a 96]
Sep 30, 2014 1:34:00 PM PoCClientServer.handlers.EchoHandler unwrap
FINER: Unwrapped 13 octets(Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING
bytesConsumed = 53 bytesProduced = 13).
Sep 30, 2014 1:34:01 PM PoCClientServer.handlers.EchoHandler unwrap
FINER: ==> [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00]
```

All seems well again... except that the plaintext was never placed into '_app'... what am I missing, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never put the payload into the application send buffer in the client, so you sent 13 null bytes.

After that, everything worked beautifully, apart from the typos.

You would think that would cause nothing to be sent, as the buffer is initially empty, but as you didn't flip() it before wrap(), it was in a state where it appeared to have 13 bytes in it.